# IE image display problems

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer

i'm working on a site at the moment: [companhiadopijama.com.br/new](http://companhiadopijama.com.br/new) and i'm having the weirdest issues with IE (7 & 8).. 6 i don't care so much about atm.

my PNG's are displaying with a partial black background on hover (in my menu) & my JPG's in the jquery roundabout are first showing up, then changing to white to black gradient.. i first had them as PNG's but had the same problem.

the code on the site is a bit messy, sorry still learning, but all the relative jquery is in [init.js](http://www.companhiadopijama.com.br/new/js/init.js) & css is in [companhiadopijama.com.br/new/css/main.css](http://companhiadopijama.com.br/new/css/main.css)

has anyone seen this before? any suggestions?

thanks in advance

b

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem with transparency in my png images. Firefox and Safari could easily handle the transparent parts, but in IE these parts were just black. Assure that there are no transparent parts in your images.

Comment: actually i'm gonna add a if IE script to replace all tranparent pngs as jpgs .. just in case.. but its the images in the roundabout below the menu that is causing me the biggest headache.. does it display the same for you? or is it rendering ok?

Comment: Sorry but I don't remember exactly. Just that there was a transparency problem with IE. And (luckily) I don't have an IE6 anymore.

Comment: unluckily a lot of my clients customers still use that dog of a browser.. so i've replaced all the transparent pngs with jpgs but still have the gradient issue on the homepage roundabout.. ahhhhh!!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you (via jQuery) are using the alpha-opacity filter for your fading effects. IE simply doesn't support transparent-PNG-plus-opacity: the alpha filter's opacity level overrides the per-pixel opacity levels, causing background pixels to lose their transparency.

With the AlphaImageLoader fix as for IE6 and the background set to white you can get a somewhat different effect, which is generally less offensive to the eye although still wrong (the less opaque of the pixel transparency and the alpha filter wins; they should of course properly be multiplied). An alternative would be to forego the fade in/out effects on IE.

Comment: well what i've done now is replace all the pngs with jpgs, so the navbar is displaying fine now.. but the roundabout, with jpgs, is still showing up then rendering as white boxes with a gradient..

Answer (score 2):

remove this from the script and that's it

```
.css('opacity', (info.opacity.min + (info.opacity.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks. In jQuery Roundabout 1.1: line 485.

Answer (score 1):

I removed that line and it works perfectly with IE7,8,9. Still it doesn't work on IE6.

For pngfix I tried "supersleight" plugin that works beautifully in every IE besides in roundabout.

I'm using a small php function to serve to IE the script without opacity:

```
            if(usingIE())
                echo "<script src='".ROOT."_js/jquery.roundabout.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
            else
                echo "<script src='".ROOT."_js/jquery.roundabout.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";


             echo "   




                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('ul#teacherslist').roundabout({
                           minOpacity: 0.6, // invisible!
                           minScale: 0.3,
                           maxScale: 1,
                           shape: 'lazySusan',
                           duration: 600,
                           minZ:2000,
                           maxZ:2001,
                           btnNext: '#next',
                           btnPrev: '#previous'
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

I still wonder why IE6 wants to give more troubles!

Answer (score 0):

it was a problem with IE handling em sizes.. i had to resize the image to 1.6% of the em size. all works now..

Comment: i had to resize the image to 1.6% of the em size...

um, Bren, could you elaborate, I have the same problem but not sure what you mean by the explanation...thanks!

Comment: hey luke,

what i did was take the size in em that works in firefox, for me it was 40em i think, and get 1.6% of its value, in this case 0.64em.

but, and this may help you more, i've upgraded to jquery 1.4 now and the problems have gone away.