# jQuery Roundabout IE images pixellated

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, carousel

at http://lunatestsite.co.uk my jQuery roundabout near the bottom of the homepage is problematic in IE7 and 8 - book cover images blurred/pixellated.

[IE image display problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985303/ie-image-display-problems/2355921#2355921)

suggests something to do with em sizing in IE being the root of it but I don't really understand the conclusion reached there. I don't think opacity is an issue in this.

Any help gratefully appreciated, this is more or less last on more checklist for this site!

Thanks

Edit: fixed by resetting to font-size: 1em before the height and width em declarations for the roundable-movable-item and roundabout-movable-item img. Now working in IE7 and 8.

Comment: Add your fix as an answer to your question and mark it accepted so this can be closed as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by resetting to font-size: 1em before the height and width em declarations for the roundable-movable-item and roundabout-movable-item img. Now working in IE7 and 8.

And then junked it :) the client wasn't happy with a less than smooth transition on IE... it did perform much better on Mac/Safari. Posted a comparison video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pzw6DTrFz

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is even coming up now in FireFox on Windows.